# Issue with dynamic Excel combo charts - handling missing data series & labels

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, office365

Good afternoon all the good people,

Let me share with you something I've been struggling with for a while. I'm using pivot tables to plot different data points next to each other on the combo charts, where the value for particular instruments are represented by column and average for given category is represented by straight horizontal line. Those pivots (after few transformations) are supplied by Power Query out from a larger 'flat' file. Each pivot table represents one data point (I know, it's not the best way but it wasn't my idea) and there are slicers attached to those pivots to change category. When particular category is selected, charts should plot instruments along with their category average.

To achieve that I'm using 'Offset' formulas to create both data series and labels, for example:  =OFFSET('Fund Level Comparison Data'!$B$6,,,COUNTIF('Fund Level Comparison Data'!$B$6:$B$500,"<>")). Here is what it looks in a nutshell, I'm not able to provide full values for column A, but you'd get the general idea:

[image: Pivot Table - Example for one attribute]

It generally does work well but major problem I have is that those charts keep crashing and change the whole layout for the random  (??) one once there is no single label item to plot, like here below. It may happen because not every single Fund reports all values, sometimes there are blanks in the source file and indeed they should as otherwise '0s' would influence the average I'm taking. Here is what it looks like under the Pivot.

[image: Pivot Table to plot the data - missing labels]

Apparently Excel is not that smart to ignore missing labels and simply don't plot anything keeping the template format, or:

1. There is another trick that I'm not aware of?
2. It goes beyond standard Excel charting capacity and I should suggest to switch into Power BI?

And here are the errors that Excel throws:

[image: Error - Example 1]

[image: Error - Example 2]

I would really appreciate any hints.

Comment: Pivot Tables filled a need in their time, but you're seeing some of their (many) limitations. Newer versions of Excel have other functions (especially "array" formulas) that might serve you better, especially when you also use "Tables" (in VBA, "ListObjects"). I suspect that approach would give you much greater ability to handle and depict your data.

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment, above, about ditching pivot tables, here is an example. A-E is generated with `=RANDARRAY(10,5)`

[image: Sample data]

The forumula for Average is `=SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2#),1,AVERAGE($A2#),0)` (note that the SEQUENCE function is used to repeat the average value for each row of data)

You can turn series on and off in the chart to isolate one or more columns:
[image: Series selection]

And if your data are tabular:
[image]

The column headers are `=TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(Table3[Attribute])))`
and the dates just omit TRANSPOSE.

Comment: Thank you @pdtcaskey, this helps to look at it from different ankles. I actually think, that instead of ditching different pivot tables I might use Power Query itself to transform the data in a similar way you have shown and then just use the set of formulas and filter to let user choose the category. Not sure how I get there yet exactly but this is something I'll have to play around with.

Comment: Turns out an interim solution is trivial and wonder why I didn't come up for this for the first place.. All you have to do is to just wrap =OFFSET with =IFERROR() formula giving it either 0 for value series or "" for text labels.